# how to check bot-user is member of specific chat or telegram channel? python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

How to check bot-user is member of specific channel  or chat member?
I'm new learner of python-telegram-bot. So , Please give me full answer. Ps. I'm using python-telegram-bot
I have used method: [get_chat_member()](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_chat_member).

```
def is_member(update, context):
    userid = update.effective_user.id
    chatid = "@chatusername"
    try:
       res = context.bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chatid, user_id=userid)
       if res.status in ['member', 'administrator']:
           return True
    except Exception as e:
       return False
```

this function only works on some chat and telegram channels but sometimes I encounter an error (telegram.error.BadRequest: User not found) . But I am sure the user is a member of the telegram channel
If you have a better solution, share it with us

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna find out a member in a group, or somewhere else, First you need to know the target group id. And then you gotta see the target user ID.

Let's retrieve this information when the user sends a message to the bot.

```
def check_user_in_the_group(update,context):

    group_chat_id = update.message.chat.id #replace this with group id number, if you already know it
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id #replace this with user id number, if you already know it


    check = context.bot.getChatMember(chat_id,user_id) #check if the user exist in the target group

    if check: #If check variable isn't null, user is in the group
        print('user is in the chat')
    else:
        print('Not found')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?